# C# WPF how to draw a circle which extends to fill its parent and remains a circle in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, constraints, ellipse

I have to draw a circle in a grid. That grid has to adapt proportionally to height and width defined by the Column/Row definition of its parent grid.
Now if I put stretch it will fill all the space and become an ellipsis while I want it to be a circle.

Ok in short the parent grid adapts proportionally like that
[image]

then in a routine I add the following code:

```
public void RadialPercentage(Grid grd )
{
    Ellipse elpExt = new Ellipse();
    elpExt.Stroke = Brushes.Green;
    elpExt.StrokeThickness = 4;
    //elpExt.Margin = new Thickness(0);
    //elpExt.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    elpExt.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
    grd.Children.Add(elpExt);

    Ellipse elpInt = new Ellipse();
    elpInt.Stroke = Brushes.Blue;
    elpInt.StrokeThickness = 4;
    elpInt.Margin = new Thickness(20);
    //elpInt.Width = elpInt.Height = dim-20;
    //elpInt.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    elpInt.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
    grd.Children.Add(elpInt);
    return;
}
```

but the effect is the following:

[image]

so it stretches both vertically and horizontally even if I only put the vertical and not the horizontal constraint. If I set it to center the ellipse collapses.

To solve the problem even I am not sure that this is the right thing to do I tried to take a look of the weight/heigth of the parent grid but obviously both those values and the actual values are set to zero.

thanks for helping
Patrick

Comment: Have a gander at [**Stretch**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.stretch(v=vs.110).aspx)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about setting `Width`'s binding to `ActualHeight` of the ellipse and set `HorizontalAlignment` to `Center`? Something like this:

```
var ellipse = new Ellipse();

var binding = new Binding(Ellipse.ActualHeightProperty.Name)
{
    RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.Self),
    Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
};

ellipse.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
ellipse.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

BindingOperations.SetBinding(ellipse, Ellipse.WidthProperty, binding);
```

Comment: Yes that might theoretically be but not in my case. Thanks a lot Maxim!!

Comment: @elgonzo Then my solution will not work. But using of `Stretch.Uniform` will not work in case of either `HorizontalAlignment` or `VerticalAlignment` is `Center` so it is not universal solution too.

Comment: True, centering the shape interferes with the (desired) size calculations :( Lemme see if i can cook up something that could be done purely in XAML and would be simple...

Comment: @elgonzo Yes, unfortunately real WPF applications contain a lot of value converters, multibindings, triggers, events magic, code behind and other "fun" things that is clear only for person who wrote all this stuff. At least first month :)

Comment: Well, and a year later down the line one forgets half about all the converters, behaviours and whatnot written and used :)... With regard to my attempts to find a way without code behind; i give up. I thought i could do perhaps something with RenderTransforms and RenderTransformOrigin, but you would still need to do a little math :(

Answer (score 0):

You can update the size of your `Ellipse` each time the parent `Grid` is resized.

You should add to your `Grid` the `SizeChanged` `Event`. XAML example:

```
<Grid Name        = "MyGrid"
      SizeChanged = "MyGridSizeChanged">
  <!-- rows and columns definitions -->
  <Ellipse Name        = "MyEllipse"
           Grid.Row    = "i"
           Grid.Column = "j" />
</Grid>
```

Now, each time the `Grid` is resized the function `MyGridSizeChanged` will executed. You should add into it code, which set sizes of your `Ellipse` equal to smallest side of contained cell. C# example:

```
void MyGridSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (sender is Grid myGrid) {
        var cellHeight = myGrid.RowDefinitions[Grid.GetRow(MyEllipse)].ActualHeight;
        var cellWidth  = myGrid.ColumnDefinitions[Grid.GetColumn(MyEllipse)].ActualWidth;
        var newSize    = Math.Min(cellHeight, cellWidth);

        MyEllipse.Height = newSize;
        MyEllipse.Width  = newSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.